# Counting the number of non-overlapping squares and cubes in a string

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, strings

Given a string S of length n that contains exactly $\lceil\frac{n}{3}\rceil$
b's and $\lceil\frac{2n}{3}\rceil$ a's:

Suppose the charge is 2 for each non-overlapping occurrence of aaa, and 1 for each non-overlapping occurrence of aa. Note the occurreces of aaa cannot overlap the occurrences of aa. Also, note that the price is the max possible.

Question:
What is the string of length n with the minimum price over all such strings?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: The cheapest string I came up with is if every other char is b, then the first 2/3 characters are uncharged, and 2/3 of 1/3 (for the last 1/3 a's) = 2/9.

Comment: Have you tried proving that it's the cheapest?

Comment: Suppose you try to decrease the charge. You move one b into the final zone of 1/3 a's. This increases the charge by 1 (at the location the b was originally) and cannot decrease the charge by more than one (although perhaps this can be done one time? depending on the divisibility of n/3 by 3)

Comment: You're describing a proof that it's a local minimum, which is different from proving that it's a global minimum. In any case, please take a few hours, and then, if you still haven't solved the question, let us know where you got stuck. We're not here to do your homework.

Comment: OK thx. Call each substring between two b's a "zone." The most expensive charge is a zone that is divisible by 3 since we pay 2 for each cube. A zone that is not divisible by 3 has a remainder of 1 or 2 a's. 2 a's would also cost, so the cheapest string would have n/3 + 1 zones, each of which has length remainder 1. (don't worry abt doing my hw, I am the one giving the hw:)

Comment: This got me worried - if you are the one giving the homework how would you *check the results*?

Comment: It's not homework at all, but a distilled version of one aspect of a problem I am trying to solve in a paper.

Comment: I don't understand the problem statement.  First you say the string is given.  Then you say the goal is to find a string.  In your first sentence you say the string must have a certain number of a's and b's; in your question at the end there seems to be no such restriction.  The title suggests yet a different question entirely.  Do you want an algorithm to do something?  If so, do what, and what are the running time requirements?  Please edit the question to provide a clearer problem statement, as right now it is not at all clear what task you're trying to solve.

Comment: Also, as Yuval says, you should spend several hours trying to solve it on your own (exhausting all the natural avenues) before asking here, regardless of whether it's homework or not... and you should show us in the question what approaches you've tried and what the best solution you've come up with so far is, so we don't repeat the work you've already done.